# Hide/show views on button tap - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, hide

I have a view, created separately in another file, that I want to show and hide conditionally when a button is pressed.

I tried several techniques like changing the opacity or offset depending on a boolean, but it doesn't work once I put the view in another SwiftUI file.

My project looks like this:

**In ContentView.swift, inside *var body: some View***

```
@State var doIWantThisViewToShow: Bool = false

MyView()
        .padding()
        .opacity(doIWantThisViewToShow ? 1 : 0)
```

**In MyView.swift**

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Text")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where is everything concerning `doIWantThisViewToShow`?

Comment: I tried to keep the mentioned code as short as possible, but yes I forgot to mention `@State var doIWantThisViewToShow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show/hide your view in different ways. Here are some that may help you:

1. `opacity` (the hidden view stays in the view hierarchy, ie. other views keep their positions):

   ```
   struct ContentView: View {
       @State var doIWantThisViewToShow: Bool = false

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               Button("Show/Hide MyView") {
                   doIWantThisViewToShow.toggle()
               }
               MyView()
                   .padding()
                   .opacity(doIWantThisViewToShow ? 1 : 0)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. `if-statement` (the hidden view is removed from the view hierarchy, ie. other views positions will be rearranged):

   ```
   struct ContentView: View {
       @State var doIWantThisViewToShow: Bool = false

       var body: some View {
           VStack {
               Button("Show/Hide MyView") {
                   doIWantThisViewToShow.toggle()
               }
               if doIWantThisViewToShow {
                   MyView()
                       .padding()
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the pawello's answer, you can hide it like:

```
MyView()
  .hidden($doIWantThisViewToShow)
```

with this simple extension

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func hidden(_ shouldHide: Bool) -> some View {
        switch shouldHide {
        case true: self.hidden()
        case false: self
        }
    }
}
```